# Javascript/Jquery Get first 100 Words from textarea string with line break

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have the following text in my textarea

```
var text = "asdf wr we rwe rwe rw er
wer
wer
wer
we
r wer we we rwe rw er
asdf wr we rwe rwe rw er
wer
wer
wer
we
r wer we we rwe rw er
asdf wr we rwe rwe rw er
wer
wer
wer
we
r wer we we rwe rw er
asdf wr we rwe rwe rw er
wer
wer
wer
we
r wer we we rwe rw erasdf wr we rwe rwe rw er
wer
wer
wer
we
r wer we we rwe rw erasdf wr we rwe rwe rw er
wer
wer
wer
we
r wer we we rwe rw erasdf wr we rwe rwe rw er
wer
wer
wer
we
r wer we we rwe rw er
asdf wr we rwe rwe rw er
wer
wer
wer
we
r wer we we rwe rw er
asdf wr we rwe rwe rw er
wer
wer
wer
we
r wer we we rwe rw er
asdf wr we rwe rwe rw er
wer
wer
wer
we
r wer we we rwe rw er";
```

now i want to extract first 100 words, from that string using jquery/javascript,
this is my code to extract words from string.

```
var wordLimit = 100;

var re ='(([^\\s]+\\s\\s*){' + wordLimit + '})(.*)';

var extractedText = text.replace(new RegExp(re, "gm"), '$1');

console.log(extractedText.match(/\S+/g).length);
```

but when i console the length of extractedText it return 165 instead of 100 which is wrong, can any one please find where i am making mistake.

Comment: Did you try to split by space and newline instead of using a regex?

Comment: No, i didnt splite the text, just extracted by regular expression.

Comment: I added an answer using split on spaces

Comment: Edited my post, it retains the line breaks

Answer (score 2):

This should help you.

The function `getWords()` returns x amount of words. I've just added `.split(" ").length` to the end of it so you can see the amount of words it returns.

```js
var text = $("#text").val()


var wordLimit = 100;

function getWords(str) {
    return str.split(/\s+/).slice(0,wordLimit).join(" ");
}

console.log("we have " + text.split(" ").length + " words")

console.log("getWords returned " + getWords(text).split(" ").length + " words");

$("#result").val(text.substring(0,getWords(text).length))
```

```css
textarea{
  height:300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="text">asdf wr we rwe rwe rw er
wer
wer
wer
we
r wer we we rwe rw er
asdf wr we rwe rwe rw er
wer
wer
wer
we
r wer we we rwe rw er
asdf wr we rwe rwe rw er
wer
wer
wer
we
r wer we we rwe rw er
asdf wr we rwe rwe rw er
wer
wer
wer
we
r wer we we rwe rw erasdf wr we rwe rwe rw er
wer
we
r wer we we rwe rw er
asdf wr we rwe rwe rw er
wer
wer
wer
we
r wer we we rwe rw erasdf wr we rwe rwe rw er
r wer we we rwe rw er
asdf wr we rwe rwe rw er
wer
wer
wer
we
r wer we we rwe rw erasdf wr we rwe rwe rw er
wer
wer
wer
we
r wer we we rwe rw erasdf wr we rwe rwe rw er
wer
wer
wer
we
r wer we we rwe rw erasdf wr we rwe rwe rw er
wer
wer
wer
we</textarea>
<textarea id="result"></textarea>
```

Comment: well,i want to retain the line breaks in text as well, your code looks like it will remove all the line break from string.

Comment: @MansoorAkhtar Take a look now at the snippet

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
//replaces newlines with spaces
text = text.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, ' ');
array = text.split(' ');
for(i=0;i<word_limit;i++) {
    //print 100 first words in console
    console.log(array[i]);
}
```

EDIT:

> well,i want to retain the line breaks in text as well.

```
var text = "asdf wr we rwe rwe rw er\nwer\nwer\nwer\nwe\nr wer we we rwe rw er\nasdf wr we rwe rwe rw er\nwer\nwer\nwer\nwe\nr wer we we rwe rw er\nasdf wr we rwe rwe rw er\nwer\nwer\nwer\nwe\nr wer we we rwe rw er\nasdf wr we rwe rwe rw er\nwer\nwer\nwer\nwe\nr wer we we rwe rw erasdf wr we rwe rwe rw er\nwer\nwer\nwer\nwe\nr wer we we rwe rw erasdf wr we rwe rwe rw er\nwer\nwer\nwer\nwe\nr wer we we rwe rw erasdf wr we rwe rwe rw er\nwer\nwer\nwer\nwe\nr wer we we rwe rw er\nasdf wr we rwe rwe rw er\nwer\nwer\nwer\nwe\nr wer we we rwe rw er\nasdf wr we rwe rwe rw er\nwer\nwer\nwer\nwe\nr wer we we rwe rw er\nasdf wr we rwe rwe rw er\nwer\nwer\nwer\nwe\nr wer we we rwe rw er";
var max = 100;
var array = text.split('\n');
var count = 0;
var new_array = [];
var last = [];
for(i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
    console.log(array[i].split(' ').length);
  count += array[i].split(' ').length;
  new_array.push(array[i]);
  if(count>=max) {
    to_remove = count - max;
    index = new_array[new_array.length-1].split(' ').length - to_remove;
    for(j=0;i<index;j++) {

      last.push(new_array[new_array.length-1].split(' ')[j]);
    }
    new_array[new_array.length-1] = last.join(' ');
    break;
  }
}
console.log(new_array.join('\n'));
total = 0;
for(i=0;i<new_array.length;i++) {
  total += new_array[i].split(' ').length;
}
console.log('total '+total);
```

Comment: well,i want to retain the line breaks in text as well.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this.

```
var extractedText = text.split(' ').slice(0,100).join(' '),
```

Comment: well,i want to retain the line breaks in text as well.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the code below..hope this will help..

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
    var text = $("#checkval").text().length;
       var limitword = $("#checkval").text().substr(0,100);
       alert(limitword);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="checkval">asdf wr we rwe rwe rw er
wer
wer
wer
we
r wer we we rwe rw er
asdf wr we rwe rwe rw er
wer
wer
wer
we
r wer we we rwe rw er
asdf wr we rwe rwe rw er
wer
wer
wer
we
r wer we we rwe rw er
asdf wr we rwe rwe rw er
wer
wer
wer
we
r wer we we rwe rw erasdf wr we rwe rwe rw er
wer
wer
wer
we
r wer we we rwe rw erasdf wr we rwe rwe rw er
wer
wer
wer
we
r wer we we rwe rw erasdf wr we rwe rwe rw er
wer
wer
wer
we
r wer we we rwe rw er
asdf wr we rwe rwe rw er
wer
wer
wer
we
r wer we we rwe rw er
asdf wr we rwe rwe rw er
wer
wer
wer
we
r wer we we rwe rw er
asdf wr we rwe rwe rw er
wer
wer
wer
we
r wer we we rwe rw er</textarea>
```